# Virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed VB on a new machine running Windows 10 Pro 1803 (build 17134.556) and running any machine instance always fails with this error:

```
The virtual machine 'linux' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\osama.shabrez\VirtualBox VMs\linux\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.


Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:   MachineWrap
Interface:   IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}
```

Here is the log:

```
4c98.360c: Log file opened: 6.0.4r128413 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000148 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa042ee00
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2019-01-16T15:03:57.845516100Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2019-01-09T05:39:12.294139300Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2019-01-16T18:11:59.832167000Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x1da658
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x74bed8b0
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x74bed8b0
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x1e1000 (1970176)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x174000 LB 0x6b3e8
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0xd8! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x1740f0 LB 0x380, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  10.0.17134.556
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     10.0.17134.556 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2019-01-16T15:03:57.425611400Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2019-01-09T17:57:37.752934500Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2019-01-16T18:11:59.769681400Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0xafe98
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x80e62f4a
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x80e62f4a
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0xb2000 (729088)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0xb0000 LB 0x520
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x90! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0xb00b0 LB 0x3a4, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  10.0.17134.556
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     10.0.17134.556 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2019-01-16T15:03:58.175408700Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2019-01-09T05:39:21.823731200Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2019-01-16T18:11:59.847788200Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x273d70
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xf0
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0xb9f4a0f1
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0xb9f4a0f1
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x273000 (2568192)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x251000 LB 0x548
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x90! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x2510b0 LB 0x3bc, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  10.0.17134.556
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     10.0.17134.556 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2018-04-11T23:34:44.042150700Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2018-04-11T23:34:44.042150700Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2018-11-29T06:23:00.356038400Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x1bd98
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xd0
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0xd02ff418
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0xd02ff418
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x1c000 (114688)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x1b000 LB 0x408
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x1b060 LB 0x3a8, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  10.0.17134.1
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
4c98.360c: Found driver tmcomm (0x8)
4c98.360c: Found driver tmevtmgr (0x8)
4c98.360c: Found driver tmactmon (0x8)
4c98.360c: Found driver tmeevw (0x8)
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x8
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tmcomm.sys:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2017-04-20T18:34:54.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2018-05-16T02:24:36.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2018-12-17T08:02:48.400245700Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x6b678
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0x100
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5adf1710
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5adf1710
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x6d000 (446464)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x6b000 LB 0x568
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x6b060 LB 0x504, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Trend Micro Eyes
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  7.0
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     7.0.0.1160
4c98.360c:     SpecialBuild:    1160
4c98.360c:     PrivateBuild:    Build 1160 - 4/24/2018
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: TrendMicro Common Module
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tmactmon.sys:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2017-04-05T22:42:40.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2018-05-16T02:24:36.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2018-12-17T08:02:48.400245700Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x20c58
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5ae97eab
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5ae97eab
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   6.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x24000 (147456)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x22000 LB 0x588
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x22060 LB 0x528, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Trend Micro AEGIS
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  2.976
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     2.976.0.2150
4c98.360c:     SpecialBuild:    2150
4c98.360c:     PrivateBuild:    Build 2150 - 5/2/2018
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: TrendMicro Activity Monitor Module
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tmevtmgr.sys:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2017-04-05T22:42:42.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2018-05-16T02:24:36.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2018-12-17T08:02:48.400245700Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x17e78
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5ae97ea9
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x5ae97ea9
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   6.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x18000 (98304)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x16000 LB 0x588
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x16060 LB 0x528, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Trend Micro AEGIS
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  2.976
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     2.976.0.2150
4c98.360c:     SpecialBuild:    2150
4c98.360c:     PrivateBuild:    Build 2150 - 5/2/2018
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: TrendMicro Event Management Module
4c98.360c: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tmeevw.sys:
4c98.360c:     CreationTime:    2015-06-08T12:54:40.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     LastWriteTime:   2017-12-05T15:02:22.000000000Z
4c98.360c:     ChangeTime:      2018-12-17T08:05:00.093967500Z
4c98.360c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
4c98.360c:     Size:            0x22ee0
4c98.360c:     NT Headers:      0xf8
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x578312e1
4c98.360c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
4c98.360c:     Timestamp:       0x578312e1
4c98.360c:     Image Version:   10.0
4c98.360c:     SizeOfImage:     0x23000 (143360)
4c98.360c:     Resource Dir:    0x1d000 LB 0x4e00
4c98.360c:     [Version info resource found at 0x90! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
4c98.360c:     [Raw version resource data: 0x2190c LB 0x4f4, codepage 0x4e4 (reserved 0x0)]
4c98.360c:     ProductName:     Trend Micro EagleEye
4c98.360c:     ProductVersion:  3.0
4c98.360c:     FileVersion:     3.0.0.1002
4c98.360c:     SpecialBuild:    1002
4c98.360c:     PrivateBuild:    Build 1002 - 7/11/2016
4c98.360c:     FileDescription: Trend Micro EagleEye Driver (VW) (amd64-fre)
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
4c98.360c: Calling main()
4c98.360c: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VirtualBoxVM fFlags=0x2
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x2): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
4c98.360c: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
4c98.360c: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
4c98.360c: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\WinSxS
4c98.360c: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\System32
4c98.360c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe' has no imports
4c98.360c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 24202 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe)
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007ffebbd14f90 pvNtTerminateThread=00007ffebbd3b3f0
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child eec.2fa4 [kernel32].
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=000000000105c000 cbPeb=0x388
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=00007ffebbca0000 uNtDllChildAddr=00007ffebbca0000
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=00007ffebbd14f90
4c98.360c: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 1 ms.
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 519 ms, 38 sleeps
4c98.360c: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
4c98.360c:  *0000000000000000-0000000000e5ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000e60000-0000000000e7ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000e80000-0000000000e98fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   0000000000e99000-0000000000e9ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000ea0000-0000000000f9afff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000f9b000-0000000000f9dfff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000f9e000-0000000000f9ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000fa0000-0000000000fa0fff 0x0040/0x0004 0x0020000 !!
4c98.360c: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Freeing exec mem at 0000000000fa0000 (LB 0x1000, 0000000000fa0000 LB 0x1000)
4c98.360c: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Free attempt #1 succeeded: 0x0 [0000000000fa0000/0000000000fa0000 LB 0/0x1000]
4c98.360c: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: QVM after free 0: [0000000000000000]/0000000000fa0000 LB 0x10000 s=0x10000 ap=0x0 rp=0x00000000000001
4c98.360c:   0000000000fa1000-0000000000faffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000fb0000-0000000000fb3fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   0000000000fb4000-0000000000fbffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000fc0000-0000000000fc0fff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000fc1000-0000000000ffffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000001000000-000000000105bfff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000000105c000-000000000105efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000000105f000-00000000011fffff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000001200000-000000007ffdffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffe0fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000007ffe1000-00007ff5922effff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ff5922f0000-00007ff592312fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   00007ff592313000-00007ff6a52dffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ff6a52e0000-00007ff6a52e0fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a52e1000-00007ff6a5353fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a5354000-00007ff6a5354fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a5355000-00007ff6a539bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a539c000-00007ff6a539cfff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a539d000-00007ff6a539dfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a539e000-00007ff6a53a2fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53a3000-00007ff6a53a3fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53a4000-00007ff6a53a4fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53a5000-00007ff6a53a8fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53a9000-00007ff6a53f1fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53f2000-00007ffebbc9ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ffebbca0000-00007ffebbca0fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbca1000-00007ffebbdaffff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbdb0000-00007ffebbdf5fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbdf6000-00007ffebbe00fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe01000-00007ffebbe0efff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe0f000-00007ffebbe0ffff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe10000-00007ffebbe12fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe13000-00007ffebbe80fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe81000-00007ffffffeffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c: VirtualBoxVM.exe: timestamp 0x5c4b51f3 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
4c98.360c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe' has no imports
4c98.360c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: cFixes=1 g_fSupAdversaries=0x8
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/1: 521 ms, 49 sleeps
4c98.360c: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
4c98.360c:  *0000000000000000-0000000000e5ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000e60000-0000000000e7ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000e80000-0000000000e98fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   0000000000e99000-0000000000e9ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000ea0000-0000000000f9afff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000f9b000-0000000000f9dfff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000f9e000-0000000000f9ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000fa0000-0000000000faffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000fb0000-0000000000fb3fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   0000000000fb4000-0000000000fbffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000000fc0000-0000000000fc0fff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000000fc1000-0000000000ffffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *0000000001000000-000000000105bfff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000000105c000-000000000105efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000000105f000-00000000011fffff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   0000000001200000-000000007ffdffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffe0fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
4c98.360c:   000000007ffe1000-00007ff5922effff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ff5922f0000-00007ff592312fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
4c98.360c:   00007ff592313000-00007ff6a52dffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ff6a52e0000-00007ff6a52e0fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a52e1000-00007ff6a5353fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a5354000-00007ff6a5354fff 0x0040/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a5355000-00007ff6a539bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a539c000-00007ff6a53a8fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53a9000-00007ff6a53f1fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c:   00007ff6a53f2000-00007ffebbc9ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c:  *00007ffebbca0000-00007ffebbca0fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbca1000-00007ffebbdaffff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbdb0000-00007ffebbdf5fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbdf6000-00007ffebbdf9fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbdfa000-00007ffebbe00fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe01000-00007ffebbe0efff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe0f000-00007ffebbe0ffff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe10000-00007ffebbe12fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe13000-00007ffebbe80fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
4c98.360c:   00007ffebbe81000-00007ffffffeffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 1444 ms and 1 fixes (loop #1).
eec.2fa4: Log file opened: 6.0.4r128413 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000004 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa042ee00
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=00007ffebbca0000 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa042ee00
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
eec.2fa4: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x74bed8b0 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
eec.2fa4: New simple heap: #1 0000000001300000 LB 0x400000 (for 1970176 allocation)
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
eec.2fa4: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
eec.2fa4: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\WinSxS
eec.2fa4: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\System32
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
eec.2fa4: Registered Dll notification callback with NTDLL.
eec.2fa4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll)
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (Input=KERNEL32.DLL, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000004001:<flags> [calling]
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ffeb8260000 LB 0x00273000 C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll [fFlags=0x0]
eec.2fa4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll)
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ffebaf50000 LB 0x000b2000 C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL [fFlags=0x0]
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffebaf50000 'C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL'
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff6a52e0000 LB 0x00112000 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe [fFlags=0x0]
eec.2fa4: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe' has no imports
eec.2fa4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 24202 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe)
eec.2fa4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
4c98.360c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0xc0000005 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 74 ms, CloseEvents);
```

I have tried everything suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837998/oracle-virtualbox-terminated-unexpectedly-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc000000 including:

1. Doing a clean (run as administrator) install after removing vb, fixing registry issues using cc and removing all unused devices using devicecleanup
2. Fixing registry key as suggested in the solution and installing drivers

I am already using the latest stable Version 6.0.4 r128413 (Qt5.6.2) and out of ideas how I can fix it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a corporate laptop, check out with the administrator, as sometimes companies are installing nasty security/monitoring apps which conflicts with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected by @kenorb, it was my company laptop and we use Trend Micro Client-Server Suit which was not letting VB do some initial configuration failing the bootup. Removing the antivirus solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat and the only clue I have is this:

> "VirtualBox 4.14 has new "hardened" security on Windows, and it doesn't play nice with anything that hooks dll's into Windows, mainly 3rd-party antivirus packages, but also any other 3rd-party program that "intercepts" Windows dll calls."

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736305/22944

source in the source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62897

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is to do a Headless Start of virtual machine.

After waiting for 60s I was able to transfer from Headless to normal by pressing show (The usual start green arrow, which has now the caption show). To my surprise it worked.

Previously received error (exit code -1073740940 (0xc0000374)) vanished.